# Rails: rake db:seed aborted, no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, seeding

When I do the following:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

This is what I get:

```
rake aborted!
no implicit conversion of nil into string    
app/mailers/base_mailer.rb:47:in '[]'
app/mailers/base_mailer.rb:47:in 'chimp_mail'
```

I think this has to do with mailchimp variables I have in my .env file. How would I pass these variables directly into bash?

Comment: you should post the base_mailer code to give us an idea of what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

**ENV**

You can only use [`ENV variables`](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html) if you have them available in your environment (OS). They are, after all, called *environment* variables:

> Operating systems (Linux, Mac OS X, Windows) provide mechanisms to set
>   local environment variables, as does Heroku and other deployment
>   platforms. Here we show how to set local environment variables in the
>   Unix shell. We also show two alternatives to set environment variables
>   in your application without the Unix shell

I think your problem will likely be that you've not got your environment variables set up in such a way that your Rails app can access them in the backend

---

**Figaro**

I would try using [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

This is a gem which allows you to create & define any number of ENV variables, and have them accessible in your development environment. I would set the env variables in the `application.yml` file that's created with Figaro and try to run the `db:seed` command again

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when working on a **Rails** 6 application with **Docker**.

The issue was that I modified my database connection strings into environment variables in the `config/database.yml` file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PORT'] %>
```

to use it in my `docker-compose.yml` file and then placed the values of the database environment variables in a `.env` file in the application root directory:

```
DATABASE_USER=my_username
DATABASE_PASSWORD=12345678
DATABASE_NAME=my_app_development
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
DATABASE_PORT=5432

RAILS_ENV=development
RACK_ENV=development
```

However, **Rails** does not natively support reading environment variables from `.env` files so the environment variable values could not be read, so it was throwing an error when I run the `rails db:drop` command:

```
Dropped database 'my_app_development'
no implicit conversion of nil into String
Couldn't drop database ''
rails aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

Add the [`dotenv-rails`](https://rubygems.org/gems/dotenv-rails) gem to your aplication `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'dotenv-rails'
```

Install the [`dotenv-rails`](https://rubygems.org/gems/dotenv-rails) gem from your console in the application root directory:

```
bundle install
```

Try running the database command that you want again. For me it was:

```
rails db:drop
```

and it should work fine this time:

```
Dropped database 'my_app_development'
Dropped database 'my_app_development'
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

The crucial piece to the puzzle that I should have mentioned is that I am using foreman. Therefore, the solution to my problem was running "foreman rake db:reset".